# I am "forcing" some control variables into a LASSO. Is it a problem that they are significantly correlated with some of the other predictors?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, modeling, lasso, regularization

I am forcing two control variables into an adaptive LASSO model. I am doing this by constraining lambda to 0 for these predictors during the second step.

I have ~40 other predictors that I would like the LASSO to select between. Some of them are significantly correlated with the two control variables. Is this a problem? Can I still take this approach?

My interest is interpreting the relationship between the predictors and the dependent variable.

Comment: Nice name ;) What do you mean by a “control” variable?

Comment: Thank you @Dave :) I mean two variables that aren't variables of interest, but just variables I would like to control for before interpreting my variables of interest.

Comment: This looks very like your other Q: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/487102/is-it-okay-to-residualize-a-variable-out-of-my-dv-as-a-way-of-dealing-with-mult ?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen It's still the same analysis, but a different question. There I was asking about residuals as a way of dealing with the issue. Here I am wondering how this colinearity affects a LASSO in which some of the colinear variables are forced in.

Comment: That's OK, but you should have linked it yourself since its the same underlying problem.

Comment: [see if this clears anything up](https://stuff.mit.edu/~vchern/papers/Chernozhukov-Saloniki.pdf), and read their later stuff if this is useful

Comment: @Nutle Thanks that's very useful! I assume it's okay to use Adaptive LASSO rather than the standard LASSO they use in the example?

Comment: @Nutle I'm actually not sure if this will work for me. I have 40 focal variables, so would I just repeat Step 2 40 times?

Comment: I suppose LASSO or Square-Root LASSO would do fine too. See e.g. slide 31. Yes, these methods usually explode with large number of parameters, but 40 is not that much. See also R package [hdm](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hdm/vignettes/hdm.pdf) for existing implementations. Note the sparsity assumption everywhere here.

Comment: @Nutle Thanks! The hdm package seems great, and almost too good to be true! Am I right that this code would perform double selection, with variables of interest in columns 1:39, and controls in 40:41?

`m <- rlassoEffects(x, y, index = c(1:39), method = "double selection", I3 = c(40,41))`

Comment: Try ``partialling out`` too, and I'd also suggest taking some time to at least read through the vignette I've linked.

Comment: @Nutle Does it matter that my data are not high-dimensional? ~40 predictors and ~1500 observations. Or is that just a bonus and I can still use this approach?

Comment: Shouldn't matter too much, but don't take my word for it, you can try experimenting with simulations, similar to your case, to be sure.